# Find values in various columns based on strings in a list python

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I have two separate excel files: sheet1 has 5 columns(name,placekey,c,pop,pclass) and sheet2  has 2 columns (sname,skey).  column placekey in Sheet1 links to column skey in sheet2. I want to be able to retrieve sname and skey based on a placekey from sheet1. I converted placekey and skey into string values based on several responses I found here but when I keep running into errors when I try to loop through each placekey to find a name. I have tried

```
#state_key.loc[k_2, state_key]
#[s for s in list if sub in s]
```

Any tips would be appreciated

Comment: Which kind of errors are you running into? Please be more specific.

Comment: `for d in k_2:`
    `s_key = state_key[[state_key].contains(k_2)]`
    `print s_key`

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'contains'

Comment: this code:
'for k in place_key:
    k_2 = k[:2]
    #print k_2
    
for i, k2 in enumerate(k_2):
    for state_key in k2:
            print k2
    states_data['STATE_KEY'].str.contains(k2)'